# Ros controller joystick

Tags: webots

I have to make Controller for Pedestrian, that will be managed with joystick (C++ and ROS). Does somebody have any Controller that does a similar function.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the controller of the pedestrian (in Python) here: https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/master/projects/humans/pedestrian/controllers/pedestrian/pedestrian.py

It is in Python, but it should be quite easy to translate it into C++.

About the Joystick, Webots does provide an API to get joystick inputs:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/joystick

This API is available both in pure C++ or with the ROS interface.